# Google Task Queue REST pull returning 500 occasionally

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, task-queue

I have Python a process leasing tasks from the [Google TaskQueue REST API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/rest/) every second in the unlimited loop:

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
task_api = googleapiclient.discovery.build('taskqueue', 'v1beta2', credentials=credentials)
while True:
    tasks = task_api.tasks().lease(...).execute()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The process sometimes run well for hours. But occasionally crashes often by one of HTTP error:

- 500 Backend Error
- 503 Backend Error
- 500 An internal error happened in the backend

The process is running on the Google Computing Engine server. It uses a service account key, specified by the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable. Is this a Google Task Queue bug or do I miss something? E.g. do I need to reread the credentials before every lease request?

Comment: backend error is flood protection google recommends you implement exponential backoff.

Comment: @DalmTo can you post a link to some documentation?

Comment: You two have the power of google search.  Google errors are system wide its good for all the APIs https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#500_backend_error

Comment: Hmm, it's about Google Drive, didn't know it applies for the Google App Engine, too.

Comment: As I said "Google errors are system wide its good for all the APIs"  400 and 500 errors are standard across Googles systems except for a weird 400 errors that can be API specific.  so yes it applies to app engine 500 errors.  500 errors are servers way of telling you that you are going to fast or its a server hiccup wait a second and try again.  it rarely takes more then 6 retries for it to kick in and respond.

Comment: Damned Google, why they do not have some General API doc linked from particular services? It's not the first time I had hit such a "feature" documented somewhere unexpectedly. Change your comment to answer and I check it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the @DalmTo has just answered in comments, I sum up his answers and add the Python solution.

The Google 5xx backed error is flood protection and Google recommends to implement [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#500_backend_error). Despite the link points to Google Drive API, the Google errors are system wide for all the APIs (GAE including). It rarely takes more then 6 retries for it to kick in and respond.

After digging the googleapiclient sources, I've found that the exponential backoff is already implemented in this library, so the solution is dead simple:

```
tasks = task_api.tasks().lease(...).execute(num_retries=6)
```

The sources of the `http.py::_should_retry_response()` shows, that beside HTTP 5xx errors the request is repeated also when the JSON response contains `userRateLimitExceeded` or `rateLimitExceeded` error.